# Connecting two databases in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source= shwn-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=database1;Integrated Security=True";

        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from table1 where A ='" + textBox1.Text.Trim() + "'", con);

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                textBox2.Text = dr["A"].ToString();
                textBox3.Text = dr["B"].ToString();
            }
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("No record  >> " + textBox1.Text.ToString());
    }
}
```

How can I connect two databases and show a certain column combined with another column from the other database?

Like in the textbox3 I want to show the B value from this database plus C value from database2, table2

Comment: Open two connections, two data readers and read the value twice.

Comment: Aside: See [SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: If I put `"'; DROP table1` in `textBox1`, your whole table will drop. You need to read up on SQL injection.

Answer (score 3):

If both databases exist in one single server, you can use database name as prefix for table name:

```
SELECT a.col1, b.col2 FROM db1.TableA a
INNER JOIN db2.TableB b ON b.Id = a.LinkId
```

[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Shouldn't that be `db1..TableA` as explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) under Multipart Names?

Comment: yes I guess it should be but as far as I remember it worked with one dot only.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *  FROM [DB1].[dbo].[Table1],[DB2].[dbo].[Table2]
```

Try to use something like above. This is just a sample, I have use this to join two table from two different database.

Comment: I would say that this doesn't add anything the other existing answer doesn't cover, but I removed my downvote as it uses a *slightly different* technique.

Comment: Hi cybermonkey, when I was start writing this solutions that time that comment was not here. When I post it then it pop-up here before me. This is not my fault !!

Comment: It took you five minutes to write that answer?